# Create SVG tag with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, svg

How do I create an SVG element with JavaScript? I tried this:

```
var svg = document.createElement('SVG');
    svg.setAttribute('style', 'border: 1px solid black');
    svg.setAttribute('width', '600');
    svg.setAttribute('height', '250');
    svg.setAttribute('version', '1.1');
    svg.setAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
document.body.appendChild(svg);
```

However it creates an SVG element with zero width and zero height.

Comment: what browser are you doing this with?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You forgot the [Namespace URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/namespaceURI) of your `svg` element and `xmlns` attribute.

Also, `version` is ignored by all browsers.

```js
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
    svg.setAttribute('style', 'border: 1px solid black');
    svg.setAttribute('width', '600');
    svg.setAttribute('height', '250');
    svg.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
    document.body.appendChild(svg);
```

Comment: "svg:svg"? Plain old "svg" will work just fine too. Also 'version' is ignored by all browsers, so it's a bit of a waste to add that.

Comment: Thanks @ErikDahlström, corrected. And what about svg.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/","xmlns:xlink","http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"); ? Is namespace realy necessary ?

Comment: If you're going to be using the `xlink:href` tag, it is absolutely necessary. Otherwise, not so much.

Answer (score 35):

`.createElementNS` is the required method for both the `svg` and `path` elements. Example below.

```js
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
var path1 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'path');
var path2 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'path');

svg.setAttribute("aria-hidden","true");
svg.setAttribute('viewbox', '0 0 24 24');
svg.setAttribute('width', '24px');
svg.setAttribute('height', '24px');

path1.setAttribute('d', 'M0 0h24v24H0z');
path1.setAttribute('fill', 'none');

path2.setAttribute('d', 'M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm-1 17.93c-3.95-.49-7-3.85-7-7.93 0-.62.08-1.21.21-1.79L9 15v1c0 1.1.9 2 2 2v1.93zm6.9-2.54c-.26-.81-1-1.39-1.9-1.39h-1v-3c0-.55-.45-1-1-1H8v-2h2c.55 0 1-.45 1-1V7h2c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2v-.41c2.93 1.19 5 4.06 5 7.41 0 2.08-.8 3.97-2.1 5.39z');
path2.setAttribute('fill', '#2962ff');

svg.appendChild(path1);
svg.appendChild(path2);
document.body.appendChild(svg);
```

Comment: For those people looking at the DOM in the Developer Tools do NOT be fooled - if you use `innerHTML` or `outerHTML` to directly assign svg markup you WILL see the `xmlns=http://www.w3.org/2000/svg` in the tag representation in the tree. If you use `createElementNS` you will NOT see it *but it is still there*! You MUST use `createElementNS` or the ns will not be there. The key gotcha for me is that when using JS and adding the `path` you don't need the explicit ns declaration with `innerHTML`, it inherits. If you use `createElement`, it does NOT inherit, so you must also use `createElementNS`.