# Android WebView: created 'svg' element not rendered

Tags: javascript, android, html, svg, webview

I am trying to put a svg element inside a WebView (Android 3.1, level 12).
My code is:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript: "
+"svg=document.createElement('svg');"
+"svg.setAttribute('width','100');"
+"svg.setAttribute('height','100');"
+"svg.setAttribute('xmlns','http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');"
+"svg.setAttribute('version','1.1');"
+"svg.innerHTML=\"<polygon points='0,0 0,100 100,100 100,0' style='stroke-dasharray:4,4;stroke-width:1;stroke:black;fill:yellow'/>\";"
+"document.body.appendChild(svg);"
); //webView.loadUrl
```

It doesn't work even adding directly the polygon child with createElementNS and setAttributeNS methods, and also without xmlns and version attributes.
Javascript is enabled in the WebView and the resulting document.body.innerHTML is correct for a svg element, simply it is not rendered.
The WebView is able to load and render a html file with similar svg inside from asset instead. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found useful what is described here: [Create SVG tag with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215021/create-svg-tag-with-javascript?rq=1)
Working code is:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript: "
+"svg=document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','svg');"
+"svg.setAttribute('width','100');"
+"svg.setAttribute('height','100');"
//+"svg.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns:xlink', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink');"
+"var svgShape=document.createElementNS ('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','polygon');"
+"svgShape.setAttributeNS(null,'points','0,0 0,100 100,100 100,0');"
+"svgShape.setAttributeNS(null,'style','stroke-width:1;stroke:black;fill:yellow;');"
+"svg.appendChild(svgShape);"
+"document.body.appendChild(svg);"
); //webView.loadUrl
```

It works also without:

svg.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns:xlink', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink');

that's in the linked example but is commented in my code.