# A created svg element with javascript makes it stuck at 0 width and height until modified by hand

Tags: javascript, svg

Edit #2: The problem might have been in a different place after all...

This is the old title if you're curious:
`document.createElementNS() and node.append() makes a node with a closing tag. How to make a node without one?`

Just skip to the bottom after the second horizontal rule.

---

**Old message:**

When it comes to js, I might do something dumb as I have the least experience in it, but want to code the front-end of a site.

I was working and experimenting with the `<svg>` element with javascript, wanted to add a new image to it, but it showed nothing.

What I saw was: the `<svg>` element had 0 width and height.

Edit: In the comments and answers below I was told that xml can have self-closing or a closing tag. I looked it up and it's true (never coded with xml so ty for telling me that!)
Still it's odd that both Firefox and Chrome don't show the element at all unless I remove the closing tag manually after the script (below) is ran.

Some searching on here led me to "switch to `createElementNS` rather than `createElement`", point is. I was already using that.

This is my code:

```js
var svgimg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "image")
svgimg.setAttributeNS(null, "height", "15")
svgimg.setAttributeNS(null, "width", "15")
svgimg.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "href", "grass_yellow.svg") // the image does exist and it's linking to it fine.
svgimg.setAttributeNS(null, "x", "0")
svgimg.setAttributeNS(null, "y", "0")
svgimg.setAttributeNS(null, "visibility", "visible")
console.log(svgimg) // printing out to see if the createElementNS is adding the closing tag.
t.appendChild(svgimg) // t = the svg element gotten via document.getElementById("")
```

Console output: (on Chrome)

```html
<image height="15" width="15" xlink:href="grass_yellow.svg" x="0" y="0" visibility="visible"></image>
```

Console output: (on Firefox)

```html
<image height="15" width="15" href="grass_yellow.svg" x="0" y="0" visibility="visible">
```

This is what's created and added in the html file's `<svg>` element: (consistent with Firefox and Chrome)

```html
<image height="15" width="15" xlink:href="grass_yellow.svg" x="0" y="0" visibility="visible"></image>
```

Hope this is enough to help you understand my issue ^^'

---

**New message:**

After some experimentation I might have figured out that the problem is caused by making an `<svg>` element with javascript.

My code originally made that `<svg>` element and when I made the example with only that code as the script and the svg element already made I was confused on why it worked. But then I might have found the issue of the bug.

For some reason making an svg element with javascript would make browsers register it as a 0 width / height element, when it has a declared height and width in the attributes. Adding a new attribute manually after the script runs makes it return back to normal.

This was the issue all along.

Btw. here's a snippet:

```js
var t = document.createElement("svg") // Making an svg element
t.setAttribute("height", "300") // Defining the size
t.setAttribute("width", "300")
document.getElementById("test").appendChild(t) // Element is added as a child of a div, but is shown immediately to have 0 width and height

var svgimg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "image") // Making an svg image element
svgimg.setAttributeNS(null, "height", "150") // Defining the size
svgimg.setAttributeNS(null, "width", "150")
svgimg.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "href", "grass_yellow.svg") // if you're gonna copy this code put your image here, thank you!
svgimg.setAttributeNS(null, "x", "0") // Defining position
svgimg.setAttributeNS(null, "y", "0")
t.appendChild(svgimg) // Adding it to the svg element

var svgrec = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect") // Making a svg rectangle
svgrec.setAttributeNS(null, "height", "150") // Defining it's size...
svgrec.setAttributeNS(null, "width", "150")
svgrec.setAttributeNS(null, "x", "150") // ... and position
svgrec.setAttributeNS(null, "y", "0")
t.appendChild(svgrec) // Adding it to the svg element
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="test" style="height: 900px; width: 900px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

See the result for yourself. Maybe now my issue is more clear ^^'

Comment: We're going to need a [mcve] here. I don't think the problem is either where you think it is or what you think it is.

Comment: Your code works for me on Chrome, Firefox, even IE11.

Comment: There are no "tags" when you're dealing with an object model. You're thinking in markup, but when you're dealing with an object model, you're working in objects, not markup. *"...makes a node with a closing tag. How to make a node without one"* How do you make a rock with only its left side? You can't, a rock is a thing, not part of a thing. It's the same with an object. *"I figured out that the closing tag shouldn't even be there as xml tags are self-closing."* No, XML tags *can be* self-closing. These are both valid XML: `<image></image>`, `<image/>`.

Comment: @RobertLongson Oh! If there's something missing about my question then I will add  more information. I never heard of a reprex before and am not sure on how to give one. Is a JSFiddle with comments enough (reading the explanaition on what a regrex is makes me think that would be) or do I need something more?

Comment: What the? Just the example works. But in the whole code it doesn't? 
What's confusing is that it's not showing anything in the whole code, unless I remove the closing tag manually after the script runs...
Are my versions outdated? https://i.imgur.com/0FVxsoE.png

Comment: @UserNotFound see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers

Comment: Thank you @RobertLongson ! I updated my question as it appear to be an issue elsewhere (I think and hope)

Comment: Your problem is that you must create the `<svg>` element itself using `document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg')`. There are dupes of this out there... Han already voted to close for missing an [MCVE] and can't update it to a dupe closing, but here is a somehow good target: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215021/create-svg-tag-with-javascript

Answer (score 1):

[An old post helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215021/create-svg-tag-with-javascript)

All I needed to do is change from creating an svg element with `createElement` to `createElementNS` and that seemed to fix it.

Sorry if I was looking for an answer in places where they weren't, but hey. At least I learned something new.

Thank you to all of you who helped me piece what's wrong with my code and teach me on new things I didn't know!