# <path> SVG not working in page when created with DOM

Tags: javascript, svg, dom, path

I'm using a simple play-icon SVG that used to work properly when created as a string. After updating the code to dynamically create the tags with JavaScript the SVGs are not showing up on the page anymore. The elements are all there, nested properly and with their correct corresponding attributes, yet the SVG icon appears 0 x 0 when inspected.

Here's the previous way they were created, which worked:

```
function createListItem(colData) {
  return `
<a class="XXXXX__list-item" target="_blank" href="${colData.url}">
<div class="XXXXX__list-icon">
    <div class="XXXXX__svg-container">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-play-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="m11.596 8.697-6.363 3.692c-.54.313-1.233-.066-1.233-.697V4.308c0-.63.692-1.01 1.233-.696l6.363 3.692a.802.802 0 0 1 0 1.393z"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="XXXXX__label"><p class="XXXXX__song"><b>${colData.songName}</b><br><span class="XXXXX__artist">${colData.artistName}</span></p>
</div>
</a>
`;
}
```

And here's the updated code of creating the same elements:

```
function svgCreate() {
  const svgNew = document.createElement("svg");
  svgNew.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
  svgNew.setAttribute("fill", "currentColor");
  svgNew.setAttribute("class", "bi bi-play-fill");
  svgNew.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "viewBox", "0 0 16 16");
  svgNew.append(pathCreate());
  return svgNew;
}

function pathCreate() {
  const pathNew = document.createElement("path");
  pathNew.setAttribute(
    "d",
    "m11.596 8.697-6.363 3.692c-.54.313-1.233-.066-1.233-.697V4.308c0-.63.692-1.01 1.233-.696l6.363 3.692a.802.802 0 0 1 0 1.393z"
  );
  return pathNew;
}
```

I've checked and compared all strings and they are identical, however in the dev-tools, some styles appear to be missing from , like: `path[Attributes Style] {d: path(...)}`, `:not(svg) {transform-origin:...}`, and from the `<svg>` parent, like: `svg[Attributes Style] {fill:...}` and `svg:not(:root) {overflow-clip-margin:... and overflow:...}`

Am I doing something wrong with the DOM? Please note that the two versions of code have been written in the same file so there are no issues with the order of the `<script>` tags in HTML or any of the CSS styles. Any help will be most welcome. Thank you!

Comment: You need to create all svg elements via `document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg")` – you don't necessarily need `setAttributeNS()` for changing attributes (unless they are namespaced).

Comment: This Stack Overflow post addresses your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56457439/a-created-svg-element-with-javascript-makes-it-stuck-at-0-width-and-height-until and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53974062. You need to set a width for the `svg` element or its container. The code snippet below with your code verifies this requirement.

Comment: Robert should not have closed this question, and link to **12 year old** answers. It is **2023**. Every modern browsers supports _native JavaScript_ Web Components you can do this with. **See:** https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/y59hspgz/

Answer (score 0):

The SVG icon displays when a `width` value is set in a CSS style style rule for the `div` element with the class `.XXXXX__svg-container`. The snippet below includes the code updates listed in @herrstrietzel's comment.

```js
let data = [{
  url: "https://www.u2.com",
  songName: "Zoo Station",
  artistName: "U2"
}];

const html = createListItem(data[0]);
document.querySelector("#list-container li:first-of-type")
  .insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", html);

function createListItem(colData) {
  return `
<a class="XXXXX__list-item" target="_blank" href="${colData.url}">
<div class="XXXXX__list-icon">
    <div class="XXXXX__svg-container">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-play-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="m11.596 8.697-6.363 3.692c-.54.313-1.233-.066-1.233-.697V4.308c0-.63.692-1.01 1.233-.696l6.363 3.692a.802.802 0 0 1 0 1.393z"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="XXXXX__label"><p class="XXXXX__song"><b>${colData.songName}</b><br><span class="XXXXX__artist">${colData.artistName}</span></p>
</div>
</a>
`;
}

function svgCreate() {
  // const svgNew = document.createElement("svg");
  const svgNew = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
  svgNew.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
  svgNew.setAttribute("fill", "currentColor");
  svgNew.setAttribute("class", "bi bi-play-fill");
  //svgNew.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "viewBox", "0 0 16 16");
  svgNew.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 16 16");
  svgNew.append(pathCreate());
  return svgNew;
}

function pathCreate() {
  const pathNew = document.createElement("path");
  pathNew.setAttribute(
    "d",
    "m11.596 8.697-6.363 3.692c-.54.313-1.233-.066-1.233-.697V4.308c0-.63.692-1.01 1.233-.696l6.363 3.692a.802.802 0 0 1 0 1.393z"
  );
  return pathNew;
}
```

```css
/* Set a width to the container */

.XXXXX__svg-container {
  width: 26px;
}

#list-container {
  list-style: none;
}

#list-container li a {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  width: fit-content;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list-container">
  <li></li>
</ul>
```