# DOM JS - object HTMLUnknownElement

Tags: javascript, dom

I have this code

```
txt = document.createElement('text');
txt.setAttribute('id', 'txt'+linesop);                                
txt.setAttribute('xml:space', 'preserve');
txt.setAttribute('font-size', '15');
txt.setAttribute('stroke', '#000');
txt.setAttribute('font-family', 'sans-serif');
txt.x = 0;txt.y = ddy;
txt.setAttribute('text-anchor', 'start');
var txtnode = document.createTextNode(arrayofStrings[indexofWord].charAt(Char));
txt.appendChild(txtnode);                                                                      
svg.append(txt);
```

You will notice that have some variables, it's not the issue here. This just create the Text element and append on SVG element. From my logs it succeeds right. At a first glance can seem haven`t reason to make mention about but it will be clarify. By the other hand, i've this...

```
var Nodes = svg.childNodes;
var numof = Nodes.length;var index;
for(var ooo=0;ooo<numof;ooo++) {
        if(txt==Nodes[ooo]) {
                index = ooo;
        }
        else {
                continue;
        }
}

var xx = Nodes[index].getBBox().width;
```

The point is the last var, xx, which intend to get the x axis of a text element, that was appended in SVG. Before someone aim out, I tried by another ways get the txt element, instead build this unusual (seemly) "for" statement. Obviously this ones are fragments, what matter is that the txt element returns as an [object HTMLUnknownElement], so can't get the value. At another moment in the same compilation the getBBox() function works well, as property of a predecessor txt element.

Trouble: var xx returns [object HTMLUnknownElement].

If someone can clarify, I will be grateful.

Comment: You need to use `createElementNS` instead of `createElement`. See [Create SVG tag with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8215021/215552)

Comment: There is no `<text>` element in the HTML namespace, you have to use  `createElementNS()` ([see on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS)) and pass the SVG namespace as argument