# How to edit svg attribute with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

```
<svg width="100", height=100">
   <polyline id="line" onclick="Click()" points="0,0 50,50" stroke-width="1" stroke="black"/>
</svg>

<script>
  var line = document.getElementById('line');
  line.style.points="0,50 0,0";
</script>
```

I wish to use javascript to generate images in page. For some reason this code has no effect. However if instead the last line was for example `line.style.stroke="green";`, it works. Why?

Comment: Points is an attribute. It's not a style. Consider using `line.setAttribute('points', '0,50 0,0')`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox thanks this worked, what is the difference between a style and an attribute?

Comment: `style` is an attribute. It contains css. We call this css “inline styles”. `points` is also an attribute. It contains text which represents points.

Comment: For explanation of **properties** versus **attributes**  read: https://javascript.info/dom-attributes-and-properties

Comment: Not a duplicate, but definitely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215021/create-svg-tag-with-javascript