# Why won't an SVG pass to HTML using a JS string literal?

Tags: javascript

In the snippet below, I have several classes on the page. I've created an array based on the list of classes. Then, I'm trying to pass a string literal to that class.

This works fine if I pass a simple string, like 'Hello World', but it won't work with an SVG.

Any ideas why? I don't get any errors with the SVG, it's just not displaying.

**Here's an example using simple HTML**

```js
const myClasses = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(myClasses, (myClass)=> {
  myClass.innerHTML = `<h3>Hello World</h3>`;
});
```

```html
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
```

**And here's another example using the same structure, but with an SVG**

```js
const myClasses = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(myClasses, (myClass)=> {
  myClass.innerHTML = `
    <svg class="myClass" width="16" height="11" viewBox="0 0 16 11" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <symbol id="btn-acc" viewBox="0 0 16 11">
        <path d="M0 2.82813L2 0.828126L8 6.82813L14 0.828126L16 2.82813L8 10.8281L0 2.82813Z" fill="currentColor" />
      </symbol>
    </svg>  
  `;
});
```

```html
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
```

Comment: `myClasses` isn't strictly-speaking an array, as you say. It's an `HTMLCollection`.

Comment: Did you inspect what gets generated? The SVG content is there. Also, change your SVG class. You keep doing a recursive loop.

Comment: I did see that. But, why isn't it displaying? Is there a more correct way to write this?

Comment: You're creating the [symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/symbol), but never use it.

Comment: @Millhorn Check this question out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215021/create-svg-tag-with-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const myClasses = document.querySelectorAll(".myClass");

myClasses.forEach((myClass) => {
  myClass.innerHTML = `
    <svg width="16px" height="11px" viewBox="0 0 16 11" fill="black" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
           <path d="M0 2.82813L2 0.828126L8 6.82813L14 0.828126L16 2.82813L8 10.8281L0 2.82813Z" fill="currentColor" />
    </svg>  
  `;
});
```

```html
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
```

Comment: You should probably explain what you did differently lol

Comment: Sorry, I made a lot of unnecessary changes. All you really need to do is remove the <symbol> tags and remove the class inside the svg. (I'm not sure why the class makes a difference, but it seems to break it for some reason.)

Comment: @NicolasGoosen How did you know to remove the symbol tags and class? Is there something about that I can read more on?

Comment: I've had to edit a lot of svg before. There's good info on css-tricks about svg. Adobe XD is also a cool (free) tool you can copy-and-paste svg directly to see what effects your code changes have.