# How can I insert existing SVG graphics with <use> tag and javascript?

Tags: javascript, svg

I am unable to display a SVG graphic built via JavaScript.
The svg is stored in the  part. I am  first correctlty displaying svg using html. If I try to display same graphic with JavaScript, nothing is displayed.
Here is my full code:

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Testing SVG insertion</title>
  <style>
    svg.defs-only {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      height: 0;
      width: 0;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: none;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  </style>
  <svg class="defs-only">
    <symbol id="shape" width="200" height="200" viewbox="0 0 200 200">
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" fill="currentColor" />
    </symbol>
  </svg>
</head>
<body style='background-color: lightGray;'>
  <h1> Testing SVG inclusion -- this works fine</h1>
  <svg style='width: 200px; height: 200px;'>
    <use xlink:href="#shape"></use>
  </svg>
  <h1> Testing SVG via javascript -- does not display anything </h1>
  <div id='container'></div>
  <script>
    let div = document.getElementById ('container');
    let svg  = document.createElement ('svg');
    svg.style.height = '200px';
    svg.style.width = '200px';
    let use  = document.createElement ('use');
    use.setAttribute("xlink:href", "#shape");
    svg.appendChild (use);
    div.appendChild (svg);
  </script>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: `document.createElement ('svg')` You need to use createElementNS.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215021/create-svg-tag-with-javascript)

Comment: In given link, you create svg, in my case I already have the svg and just want to use it.Where should I put my #shape?

Comment: I finally have a fix :      let div = document.getElementById('container');
    let svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
    svg.setAttribute('width', '200');
    svg.setAttribute('height', '200');
    svg.setAttribute('display', 'block');
    let use = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'use');
    use.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', '#shape');
    svg.appendChild(use);
    div.appendChild(svg);

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `use.setAttribute("xlink:href", "#shape");` with `use.setAttribute("href", "#shape");`
Is due to the deprecation of xlink in SVG 2.0 specifications.

Comment: Just tried it and it does not work ...